# CSS Custom font not showing properly in web host but localhost

Tags: php, html, css, fonts

I'm trying to add a custom font to my website.

**CSS code**

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'dhananjayawebregular';
src: url('dhananjaya_web_sinhala_font-webfont.eot');
src: url('dhananjaya_web_sinhala_font-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('dhananjaya_web_sinhala_font-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('dhananjaya_web_sinhala_font-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('dhananjaya_web_sinhala_font-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('dhananjaya_web_sinhala_font-webfont.svg#dhananjayawebregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

```
#sinhala {font-family:dhananjayawebregular;}
#dhananjayaweb {font-family:dhananjayawebregular;}
```

**PHP code**

```
                    <div class="cell">
                    <a href="<?php echo "$name_html-news$id.html";?>">
                        <div class="newstitle" id="dhananjayaweb"><?php echo $title;?></div>
                        <div class="newsname"><?php echo $name;?></div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="shortnews" id="dhananjayaweb"><?php echo substr($news1, 0, strpos($news1, ' ', 140));?>&#39&#39&#39</div>
                    <div class="newsother">
                        <?php echo $views;?> views |
                        Date : <?php echo $date;?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

But it works properly in localhost(windows) only. When I upload the script into web host(Linux), the fonts does not show properly

[screenshot on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9jhl.png)

[Screenshot on web host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Ekz.png)

I tried all the things I could find on the web, but still not working. Im desperately trying to get this to work. Please help.

Comment: you could try adding `/` before the paths

Comment: eg `src: url('/dhananjaya_web_sinhala_font-webfont.eot');`

Comment: can you explain why? it did nothing still.

Comment: the slash indicates that the resource is located on the server. however most server are set up to defaultly look on the server unless they see `"http://"`.

Comment: in my case, it reads the font, but do not show properly, like its wrapped or something. look here http://pituva.com/

Comment: so the problem is not the resources being located it is the layout of the page

Comment: it would also help if you open the page on localhost and on the host and used the `inspect` option of your browser to view the code that is generated for each page

Comment: do you know what could cause something like this? it works fine when uploaded separately like this http://pituva.com/test1.php

Comment: it may be because when it is in the container it is on multiple lines i added line breaks in the link and this changed the character that were displayed i am not sure how to fix this of than tactical spacing

Comment: One difference between Windows and Linux is that filenames are case insensitive in Windows. So are you sure the font files have those exact names, with only lowercase letters?

Comment: @Mr Lister @ AlexanderRD I manage to fix it guys thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its a shame to say but I forgot to add this line on the header :D

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

everything is fine now.
Thanks everyone for trying to help, really appreciate the help.